# Xcode Debug panel is gone

Tags: ios, xcode

I installed Cocoapods and started running the project from the new `app.xcworkspace` file. My target is an app extension (Keyboard extension). Everything works great, except that I can't see the debug panel anymore. In other words, breakpoints or print statements have no effect.

In order to fix this, I checked the scheme and made sure that I'm running the debug version instead of release version.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, been there done that. See the last 3 icons on the top right?

Click the middle one (which has the dark bar in at the bottom), when it is blue, the debug view will come up.

[image: Icon set for debug view]

Comment: Before even if I had the panel activated, the logs weren't showing. Cleaning the build, uninstalling the app from the simulator, and toggling the debug panel seemed to solve the problem!

Comment: Aha, there you go! Sometimes it just takes the equivalent of the classic "have you turned it off and on again", haha.